# How to save image from internet to SQL CE and restore?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, arrays

I have lots of pictures as links, and they must be loaded into the database, or in Isolated Storage.And then get them to Image.

Comment: Save images to `Isolated Storage` as they have been downloaded. Save file paths to images, also. Then you can load them when needed. What of that you can't implement? Please, make question more specific.

Comment: I mean, it would upload pictures once, and then load them from a local store. The problem is that I can not convert the picture into byte [] and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can not convert the picture into byte [] and vice versa.

When you download picture from a server - it's already a byte array. So, you can save it with next code:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile Store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
 IsolatedStorageFileStream filestream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Path,           FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, Store);
 int bytesRead = 0;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[Int16.MaxValue];
 do
 {
      bytesRead = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, Int16.MaxValue);
      filestream.Write((buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
 while (bytesRead > 0);
 stream.Close();
```

For download image from IsoStore, use this:

```
 if (IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().FileExists(Path))
            {
                BitmapImage Image = new BitmapImage();

                using (IsolatedStorageFile Store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream Stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, Store);

                    if (Stream.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Image.SetSource(Stream);
                    }

                    Stream.Close();
                }

                return Image;
            }
```

Comment: I can not understand where we download the file. What is a variable serverStream. I have a exception in the second line.

Comment: `serverStream` is a image stream downloaded from a server. Please, decompose your question into smaller tasks. There are a lot similar questions were here.